# JSON data send could not complete

Tags: json, .net, httpwebrequest

I am getting an error (**the remote server returned an error 500. Internet server error**) when sending JSON data to a remote server: here is the code

if I run the code on my local system, it works.

**Please help me to fix this problem.**

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://www.xxx.xom/rec/jsonrw/jsonwrite.php"), HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.ContentLength = json.Length
Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
streamWriter.Write(json)
streamWriter.Close()
Dim httpResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim s As String
s = httpResponse.ToString
```

Comment: There is too little information to help you. The Internal Server Error 500 is a collective status code for server errors. At first glance it is not possible to see where the fault actually lies. You only learn: The server reports an unexpected error. You need to - at the very least - add the infowhat kind of server you are trying to send data to and how the json actually looks. Even then it is not guaranteed that people will be able to help you, but then they at least have a chance. If you are in control of the server, I would suggest looking at its log files, your answer is most likely there.

Comment: I am connecting to a database which is in GoDaddy, and the data looks like {
  "dsResBooking": [
    {
      "GSTNAM": "Mr NEERAJ  SHARMA",
      "userid": "SUNITA",
      "GRPNAM": " ",
      "PRPCOD": "JNP",
      "ROMTYP": "PLC"
      
    }
    
  ]
}

Comment: my API in php, do I need to add RequestVerificationToken headers in HttpWebRequest. I haven't tried this.